# What could cause a tap to flow well, then spurt?

Tags: plumbing, taps

I fitted a new tap to a sink, single cold water tap. When I first turned it on the water ran fine. If I  open the tap further, the water flow becomes jerky with constant gaps in the flow.

Is this the tap that is malfunctioning or the delivery?

Comment: Did you replace the tap for a specific reason, ie the spurting?

Comment: Do you have a pump system or delivery from a municipal line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you turned the water off to install the faucet.  This usually means that air is introduced into the piping, and can cause spurting as it bleeds out.  Leave the water running for a few minutes and see if it stops.

Also, ensure that you've turned any shut-offs all the way back on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes the water was turned off before fitting. It has been behaving like this for some months. I will check all the shut-offs are fully open.

Comment: Thanks Chris I should have checked this anyway but the shut off tap was only a little open, opened it all the way now it works, must have been one of the kids ;-), cheers.